printJS remove Headers and footers plus show CSS background color of row
We are trying to implement a feature where the user can print an HTML segment of our app, we generate spreadsheet data in a div and then plan to use printJS to print it (we call printJS with the name of our div and type html). Overall it works great but the print result displays the footer and header (URL and document title which we do not want to show the user, plus it does NOT display the uneven row color that we use, we color uneven rows in the spreadsheet for readability). In the HTML the colors shows correctly.
I've been trying to solve this issue by forcing this behavior with the following code in our index.html
 <style type="text/css" media="print">
     @page {
         size: auto;
         margin: 0;
     }

     * {
         -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
         color-adjust: exact !important;
         print-color-adjust: exact !important;
     }
 </style>

This code works and shows desired result IF the user deselects "Headers and footers" in the Windows print dialog, and also checks the "Background graphics" checkbox.
It won't be a desired customer solution if the user needs to make these settings in the Windows print dialog each time they gonna print and its tricky to add this to the instructions. We would like to be able to show the row colors plus remove the headers and footers without any setting needed from the user (i.e. programmatically).
How can we programmatically achieve this? I am not sure but it seems like Windows store these settings somehow but we would prefer if these settings/properties are taken care of via our code if possible. Really appreciate any help! Totally stuck on how to proceed. Only relevant for printing on Windows.
